# Where to put REST Assured tests

Tags: java, integration-testing, rest-assured

Is it a common practice to put REST Assured tests in the same project it will test, or in its own project? 
Like, I have a microservice called purchase which I will write the tests for. Should the tests be in it, or should I create another project to do it, named some like purchase-integration-tests?

Thanks!

Comment: Anyone? =/ ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to share the practice which we use in our project:

Our microservice code is structured into multiple project with one parent. Within the parent project we have below child projects:

1. Spec- Contains Swagger Spec
2. Service- Contains Service Code
3. Integration Tests
4. Load tests

As part of the CI/CD pipeline, first the code is build and unit tested, then integration tests which are rest assured based are triggered where all your dependent services are mocked with the help of wiremock, then you have load tests. Build is deployed to the environment after the successful, completion of all the projects.

Apart from this we also have regression test cases written for specific environments using rest assured as independent project.

Comment: Solid structure, thank you very much for answering! I didn't really understand how the parent works. Can you please give me a little more details on it?

Comment: POM.xml of your parent project should contain the child as modules. you can use he modules tag to specify each child in the POM.

Comment: Rest assured is for e2e testing which is different from integration testing.  Being e2e testing, it is potentially dangerous as it can pollute backed.  That is the only reason I can think of it should be in a separate project so it runs only in"backend safe" profile

Answer (score 0):

**If you have more than one API project or your tests are written by QA** I recommend keeping them in a separate repository.  It allows a single set of RestAssured tests to conveniently validate data across multiple APIs which may live in different projects, and it maintains separation between QA and Development.  They would generally go under `src/test/java` and not `src/main/java` since they are tests.  They could go under `main` if you have any intention of writing test code for your RestAssured tests.

**If you only have one API project and your tests are written by devs**, then it makes sense to put them in the same project as the endpoints they test.  In this case, they should go under `src/test/java/com/yourcompany/restassured` but make sure you keep them in a separate package from the unit tests.